# Is there any easy way to convert this specific number form to Moment in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

so I have a bunch of times that look like this:

```
12.5
17.5
```

And so on, and 12.5 basically represents 12:30 pm, 17.5 represents 5:30 and so on. I want to convert these into moments in the form `HH:mm a`, is there a built-in function for this or will I have to write a function for this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a combination of the `.startOf()` method and the `.add()` method to achieve what you're after?

For example:

```
moment().startOf('day').add(12.5, 'hours').format('hh:mm a') // 12:30 pm
moment().startOf('day').add(17.5, 'hours').format('hh:mm a') // 17:30 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertTime(time) {
  var hour = Math.floor(time);
  var fraction = time - Math.floor(time);
  var min = Math.floor(fraction * 60);
  if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + String(min);
  } else {
    min = String(min);
  }
  newTime = String(hour) + ":" + min;
  return newTime;
}
```

I'm assuming based on the format `HH:mm a` that you're okay rounding the minutes. This will round them down, but you can use Math.round if you want to actually round them to the nearest minute.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I actually don't have a problem with writing the actual function lol, I was just wondering if there are any alternatives as I would rather not write a new function for other reasons. Thanks anyway though!